# Add blank row to MySQL query results based upon change in column value

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting

If I have a typical MySQL query such as:

```
SELECT CommentNo, CreatedDate, CreatedTime, Text FROM Comment
```

The results will be displayed in a simple table. But is it possible to have MySQL format the output so that a blank line can be inserted into the results based upon a change in a column?

So if my query above returns the following by default:

```
 CommentNo CreatedDate CreatedTime Text
 1         2012-08-02  15:33:27    This.
 2         2012-08-02  15:34:40    That.
 3         2013-06-30  19:45:48    Something else.
 4         2013-06-30  21:26:01    Nothing.
 5         2013-06-30  21:26:43    Was.
 6         2013-07-01  13:40:32    Hello.
 7         2013-07-01  14:08:25    Goodbye.
```

Is it possible to insert a blank row upon change of column value for `CreatedDate`, so I get:

```
 CommentNo CreatedDate CreatedTime Text
 1         2012-08-02  15:33:27    This.
 2         2012-08-02  15:34:40    That.

 3         2013-06-30  19:45:48    Something else.
 4         2013-06-30  21:26:01    Nothing.
 5         2013-06-30  21:26:43    Was.

 6         2013-07-01  13:40:32    Hello.
 7         2013-07-01  14:08:25    Goodbye.
```

The above is not how data would be stored in the Comment table, it is an issue of formatting query output.

Or would it be better to use a `BufferedWriter` in Java?

Comment: It's possible, but a very bad idea to do this at the database level. This should be part of your presentation code.

Comment: This would be in the formatting of the query output by MySQL. Ideally I want to include the blank lines when writing the data to a csv file. The blanks would not be stored in the database tables.

Comment: You can use Offset value for insertion of space in database. But that's not a desired way to store data.

Comment: Again, the data would not be stored with blank rows. My question relates to query output only.

Comment: Again, it's possible, but don't have your database do that kind of formatting, even for query output. Whatever program sends the query to MySql should take the results and insert the blank lines as it writes the csv data.

Comment: So if I want to have the blank row between groups of sets of results, would a Java `BufferedWriter` be better to write the `.csv` file?

Comment: php excel is good if u work on php

Comment: I'm using Java though.

Comment: It's basically the same in any language. After you print a row, save the value of that column in a variable. Before printing each row, check whether the current value is different from the variable. If it is, print a blank line.

Comment: Using variables in the query. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have adapted the code found at: [enter link description here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/csv-commons/writeread-csv-files-with-apache-commons-csv-example/.) which can easily be extended to include a line when parsing the data to write the .csv file.

```
// Iinitialise FileWriter object.
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);

        // Iinitialise CSVPrinter object/ t.
        csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);

        // Create .csv file header.
        csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

        // Write a new student object list to the .csv file.
        for (Student student : students) {
            ArrayList studentDataRecord = new ArrayList();
            studentDataRecord.add(String.valueOf(student.getId()));
            studentDataRecord.add(student.getFirstName());
            studentDataRecord.add(student.getLastName());
            studentDataRecord.add(student.getGender());
            studentDataRecord.add(String.valueOf(student.getAge()));
            csvFilePrinter.printRecord(studentDataRecord);
            csvFilePrinter.println();
        }
```

Although I have yet to add code to determine the change in the column value required but that is straightforward.

Comment: Answer is different than the question, which only talks about SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that this type of formatting should definitely be done at the application layer and not as a query.

That said, this seems like an amusing exercise, and it isn't so hard:

```
select CommentNo, CreatedDate, CreatedTime, Text
from (select c.*, CreatedDate as key1, 0 as ordering
      from comment c
      union all
      select c2.*, c.CreatedDate, 1
      from (select distinct CreatedDate from comment c) c left join
           comment c2
           on 1 = 0
     ) c
order by key1, ordering, id;
```

Note the use of the `left join` in the second subquery to bring in all the columns, so it matches the `select *` in the first subquery.  However, getting rid of the last two columns still requires listing all of them.

Comment: I like this, but I agree that it is not something to include at the database level. But I have opted for another approach and have posted it as my solution.